# Where I can find the best best step by step training for building LSTM in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer

Team,

I wonder of anyone has found a good (for dummies :-) documentation for creating LSTM networks in Keras? Specifically about the expected size of the input, layers and output. E.g. Expected input batch shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim). The Keras.io documentation isn't really clear. I'm using the Keras visualization (this is helping me).

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://machinelearningmastery.com a lot.

Some examples regarding LSTM networks:

http://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

http://machinelearningmastery.com/understanding-stateful-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Wilmar. Thank you for you quick reply. Dr. Jason did a good job. However, you can see there are some post clarification I made. For example, I beleive the data should be spit ramdonly instead a fixed training and validation set. Second, the results in term of equare error is terrible (+50 error, it's better to use a coin for clasification). Now, Dr. Jason's post doesn't explain the  expected input/output batch shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim). What if a new class is added for example?

Comment: Whatever split method or ratio you use is your own choice. Low accuracy can be caused by lot's of factors. And from the tutorials you should be able to derive how the input/output shape is defined. If not, there are plenty of other examples (e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674713/neural-network-lstm-input-shape-from-dataframe and http://danielhnyk.cz/predicting-sequences-vectors-keras-using-rnn-lstm/). Some are a bit cryptic but with a little effort you will understand the explanations.

Comment: Just fund a post that helped me to resolved the issued http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674713/neural-network-lstm-input-shape-from-dataframe

Answer (score -1):

Basically, a good way to understand the batch size, clases, timesteps and data dim using pandas DataFrames is available in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674713/neural-network-lstm-input-shape-from-dataframe)