# How to shape large DataFrame for python's keras LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, reshape

I nearly found what I need in the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674713/neural-network-lstm-input-shape-from-dataframe/40005797#comment95518433_40005797). But had memory issues because the test df provided was only 11 rows.

What I'm trying to predict is using **LSTM to forecast 10 days ahead** of a **Time Series** data in a **regression** model (not classifier!). My **dataframe** `X` has around **1500 rows and 2000 features**, being of `shape (1500, 2000)` while the **truth values** `y` are just **1500 rows** of 1 feature (that can `range any value between -1 and 1`).

**Since LSTM needs 3D** vector as an **input**, I'm really **struggling how to reshape the data**.

Again, following the example at first paragraph, it crashes for MemoryError when padding values, more specifically at `df.cumulative_input_vectors.tolist()`.

My **test** (read forecast) is a **dataframe of `shape (10, 2000)`**.

**Due to sensitive data I can't actually share the values/example**. How can I help you help me with this?

So, **to enable the LSTM to learn from the 1500 rows of `y`**, **how** should I **reshape my `x` of 1500 rows and 2000 features**? **Also**, **how** should I **reshape my `forecast` of 10 rows and 2000 features**?

They'll undergo -at first because I'm learning LSTM- a simple LSTM model of:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_X, train_y , epochs=50, batch_size=2, verbose=1)
```

what I've tried, but when predictin got error:

```
# A function to make a 3d data of what I understood needed done:
def preprocess_data(stock, seq_len):
    amount_of_features = len(stock.columns)
    data = stock.values

    sequence_length = seq_len #+ 1
    result = []
    for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
        result.append(data[index : index + sequence_length])

    X_train = np.array(result)  

    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], amount_of_features))

    return X_train

# creating the train as:
# X == the DF of 1500 rows and 2000 features
window = 10
train_X = preprocess_data(X[::-1], window)
```

Comment: Please restructure your question and make it clear what exactly you're asking. Right now I'm confused because it seems like you're asking a reshape question then somehow you're managing to run prediction but getting an error there instead?

Comment: I don't see whats the confusion, what is the sentence/name of the question? Tip: its how should I reshape. The body is just a full explanation of where I am to avoid unhelpful answers of "possible duplicate of.."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while I've managed to understand properly what the dimensions where. Keras expect a 3d array of `.shape` **(totalRows, sequences, totalColumns)**. The `sequences` one was the most confusing to me.

That was because when reshaping the df `df.reshape(len(df), 1, len(df.columns))` meaning **keras** would learn for a matrix of 1 line it gave me bad results because I didn't know **it's best to scale the data** for me **`MinMaxScaler(-1,1)`** **worked best**, but could be `(0,1)`.

**What made me understand** that was to first **use sequence of more than 1 row (or days, since my dataset was a Time Series)**. Meaning that **instead of feeding 1 row of features X results in 1 value of y**, **I used** something like **5 rows of features X results in 1 value of y**. as in:

```
# after scaling the df, resulted in "scaled_dataset"
sequences = 5
result = []
# for loop will walk for each of the 1500 rows
for i in range(0,len(scaled_dataset)):
    # every group must have the same length, so if current loop position i + number 
    # of sequences is higher than df length, breaks
    if i+sequences <= len(scaled_dataset):
        # this will add into the list as [[R1a,R1b...R1t],[R2a,R2b...R2t],...[R5a,R5b...R5t]]
        result.append(scaled_dataset[i:i+sequences].values)
# Converting to array + keras takes float32 better than 64
train_x = np.array(result).astype('float32')
# making the y into same length as X
train_y = np.array(y.tail(train_x.shape[0]).values)

train_x.shape, train_y.shape
```

> '>>> (1495, 5, 2400), (1495,)

**Writen in another way the mentality on keras shapes for my problem:**

Considering it's a time series, above means that 5 days (rows 0 to 4) of data results in the value y of row 5.

Then, less the first day + the next day after last - still 5 days - (rows 1 to 5) of data results in the value y of row 6.

Then, less the second day + the next day after last - still 5 days - (rows 2 to 6) of data results in the value y of row 7.

It's quite confusing for starters of keras/LSTM, but I hope I could details this for people who might land here.

Comment: I am also using this method. However looping through a large dataframe is extremely slow.